# Symfony column type text

Tags: database, symfony1

I want a column in my database to be of type text (an unlimited amount of text).

In my schema:

`bio: { type: text }`

Migration file generated:

```
$this->changeColumn('organization', 'bio', 'text', '', array());
```

When I try to migrate I get the following error:

```
- SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1. Failing Query: "ALTER TABLE organization CHANGE bio bio text()"
```

What is the correct syntax for such a field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use "string" instead of "text"

```
bio: { type: string }
```

Comment: maybe you can help me with a similar problem? I'm adding another field of type `varchar(255)` (in migration file its: `'string', '255'`) and it's giving me an error that row size is too large. It says my max is 65535, but this is only 255. Is the max all text fields in the table together?

Comment: Hmmm... Are you sure it's for that field?

Comment: It seemed that there were too many string fields in my table. As soon as I took some unused fields out, it worked.